# How to retrieve a list of all market pairs like ETH/BTC using Binance API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, binance

I am working on a project relevant to crypto trading where I need to select a market pair of Binance Exchange and based on the pair choice I have to show various results like current price, 24 Hr price change, 24 Hr Volume and last 10 trade history of that market pair. I have gone through Binance Rest API Docs: https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md ,and can't find the endpoint which can help me retrieve a list of market pairs.
Is there any documentation I am unaware about?

Thanks.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You are looking for the `/exchangeInfo` public endpoint.

See more at https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md :

**Exchange information**

`GET /api/v1/exchangeInfo`

Current exchange trading rules and symbol information

Resulting `symbols` array of all coin pairs:

```
...
"symbols": [{
"symbol": "ETHBTC",
"status": "TRADING",
"baseAsset": "ETH",
"baseAssetPrecision": 8,
"quoteAsset": "BTC",
"quotePrecision": 8,
"orderTypes": [
  // These are defined in the `ENUM definitions` section under `Order types (orderTypes)`.
  // All orderTypes are optional.
],
"icebergAllowed": false,
"filters": [
  // There are defined in the `Filters` section.
  // All filters are optional.
]
}]
...
```

Comment: That repository has been moved to https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md

Comment: well, I found in the Binance API document it's better to use Websocket. because the server bans the IP.

Comment: Quick note. Check the status field on these as hundreds get returned that aren't tradable. Only the ones with a status of TRADING can be traded.

Answer (score 29):

For `python` users that ended up here after googling "*binance api trade pairs*" :

```
from binance.client import Client

api_key = "xxx"
api_secret = "xxx"

client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
exchange_info = client.get_exchange_info()
for s in exchange_info['symbols']:
    print(s['symbol'])
```

---

```
ETHBTC
LTCBTC
BNBBTC
NEOBTC
QTUMETH
EOSETH
SNTETH
BNTETH
...
```

Comment: Exactly what I searched for, thanks. This is, as expected, for the `python-binance` module. It is a little bit confusing because the official `binance-connector` from Binance also installs as `binance` and has similar calls, but they clash and can't be installed both.

Answer (score 26):

I think it would be easier to create dump of the coin list and place here for new developers

```
["BTC","LTC","ETH","NEO","BNB","QTUM","EOS","SNT","BNT","GAS","BCC","USDT","HSR","OAX","DNT","MCO","ICN","ZRX","OMG","WTC","YOYO","LRC","TRX","SNGLS","STRAT","BQX","FUN","KNC","CDT","XVG","IOTA","SNM","LINK","CVC","TNT","REP","MDA","MTL","SALT","NULS","SUB","STX","MTH","ADX","ETC","ENG","ZEC","AST","GNT","DGD","BAT","DASH","POWR","BTG","REQ","XMR","EVX","VIB","ENJ","VEN","ARK","XRP","MOD","STORJ","KMD","RCN","EDO","DATA","DLT","MANA","PPT","RDN","GXS","AMB","ARN","BCPT","CND","GVT","POE","BTS","FUEL","XZC","QSP","LSK","BCD","TNB","ADA","LEND","XLM","CMT","WAVES","WABI","GTO","ICX","OST","ELF","AION","WINGS","BRD","NEBL","NAV","VIBE","LUN","TRIG","APPC","CHAT","RLC","INS","PIVX","IOST","STEEM","NANO","AE","VIA","BLZ","SYS","RPX","NCASH","POA","ONT","ZIL","STORM","XEM","WAN","WPR","QLC","GRS","CLOAK","LOOM","BCN","TUSD","ZEN","SKY","THETA","IOTX","QKC","AGI","NXS","SC","NPXS","KEY","NAS","MFT","DENT","IQ","ARDR","HOT","VET","DOCK","POLY","VTHO","ONG","PHX","HC","GO","PAX","RVN","DCR","USDC","MITH","BCHABC","BCHSV","REN","BTT","USDS","FET","TFUEL","CELR","MATIC","ATOM","PHB","ONE","FTM","BTCB","USDSB","CHZ","COS","ALGO","ERD","DOGE","BGBP","DUSK","ANKR","WIN","TUSDB","COCOS","PERL","TOMO","BUSD","BAND","BEAM","HBAR","XTZ","NGN","DGB","NKN","GBP","EUR","KAVA","RUB","UAH","ARPA","TRY","CTXC","AERGO","BCH","TROY","BRL","VITE","FTT","AUD","OGN","DREP","BULL","BEAR","ETHBULL","ETHBEAR","XRPBULL","XRPBEAR","EOSBULL","EOSBEAR","TCT","WRX","LTO","ZAR","MBL","COTI","BKRW","BNBBULL","BNBBEAR","HIVE","STPT","SOL","IDRT","CTSI","CHR","BTCUP","BTCDOWN","HNT","JST","FIO","BIDR","STMX","MDT","PNT","COMP","IRIS","MKR","SXP","SNX","DAI","ETHUP","ETHDOWN","ADAUP","ADADOWN","LINKUP","LINKDOWN","DOT","RUNE","BNBUP","BNBDOWN","XTZUP","XTZDOWN","AVA","BAL","YFI","SRM","ANT","CRV","SAND","OCEAN","NMR","LUNA","IDEX","RSR","PAXG","WNXM","TRB","EGLD","BZRX","WBTC","KSM","SUSHI","YFII","DIA","BEL","UMA","EOSUP","TRXUP","EOSDOWN","TRXDOWN","XRPUP","XRPDOWN","DOTUP","DOTDOWN","NBS","WING","SWRV","LTCUP","LTCDOWN","CREAM","UNI","OXT","SUN","AVAX","BURGER","BAKE","FLM","SCRT","XVS","CAKE","SPARTA","UNIUP","UNIDOWN","ALPHA","ORN","UTK","NEAR","VIDT","AAVE","FIL","SXPUP","SXPDOWN","INJ","FILDOWN","FILUP","YFIUP","YFIDOWN","CTK","EASY","AUDIO","BCHUP","BCHDOWN","BOT","AXS","AKRO","HARD","KP3R","RENBTC","SLP","STRAX","UNFI","CVP","BCHA","FOR","FRONT","ROSE","HEGIC","AAVEUP","AAVEDOWN","PROM","BETH","SKL","GLM","SUSD","COVER","GHST","SUSHIUP","SUSHIDOWN","XLMUP","XLMDOWN","DF","JUV","PSG","BVND","GRT","CELO","TWT","REEF","OG","ATM","ASR","1INCH","RIF","BTCST","TRU","DEXE","CKB","FIRO","LIT","PROS","VAI","SFP","FXS","DODO","AUCTION","UFT","ACM","PHA","TVK","BADGER","FIS","OM","POND","ALICE","DEGO","BIFI","LINA"]
```

Comment: That was actually a pretty good idea. Thank you!

Comment: It would be even better to show how to create that dump.

Comment: @Spartan
I do it like this
```typescript
const currencies = symbols.reduce<string[]>((acc, item) => {
      if (!acc.includes(item.baseAsset)) {
        acc.push(item.baseAsset);
      }

      if (!acc.includes(item.quoteAsset)) {
        acc.push(item.quoteAsset);
      }

      return acc;
    }, []);
```

Where `symbols`

```json
{
    "symbol": "ETHBTC",
    "status": "TRADING",
    "baseAsset": "ETH",
    "baseAssetPrecision": 8,
    "quoteAsset": "BTC",
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Just change the "quote" variable with the quote asset you want. Then after you launch the script, you will get a "allTargets" file with all the base assets

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs')
var quote="USDT"
var options = {
  'method': 'GET',
  'url': 'https://api.binance.com/api/v1/exchangeInfo',
  'headers': {
  }
};
request(options, function (error, response) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  //console.log(JSON.parse(response.body));
  var symbols = JSON.parse(response.body).symbols
  var justUSDTpairs = symbols.map((x)=>{
    if(x.quoteAsset.includes(quote)){
      return x.baseAsset
    }
  }).filter((x)=>{if(x){return x}})
  fs.writeFileSync('allTargets',JSON.stringify(justUSDTpairs))
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this public API can help you.

```
https://api3.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price
```

Answer (score 3):

For those using the official [binance-connector](https://github.com/binance/binance-connector-python) from Binance:

```
from binance.spot import Spot as Client

client = Client()
exchange_info = client.exchange_info()
usdt = set()
for s in exchange_info['symbols']:
    if s['symbol'].endswith('USDT'):
        usdt.add(s['symbol'])
print(usdt)
print(len(usdt))
```

Gives you a set with all unique Base/USDT pairs.

Pedro Lobito's answer is for [python-binance](https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance) which for 90% of the users is what they want, but for the rest it might be confusing as both install as `binance` and can't be installed together because of the name clash.

Answer (score 1):

Geting all of the infos in a single `DataFrame` in python using `pandas` and [python-binance](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

```
from binance.client import Client
import pandas as pd

api_key = ''
api_secret = ''

client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
symbols = client.get_exchange_info()
i = 0
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=symbols[0].keys())
for sym in symbols:
    for key in sym.keys():
        df.at[i, key] = sym[key]
    i = i + 1


df
         symbol  ...     permissions
0        ETHBTC  ...  [SPOT, MARGIN]
1        LTCBTC  ...  [SPOT, MARGIN]
2        BNBBTC  ...  [SPOT, MARGIN]
3        NEOBTC  ...  [SPOT, MARGIN]
4       QTUMETH  ...          [SPOT]
         ...  ...             ...
1710  CHESSBUSD  ...          [SPOT]
1711  CHESSUSDT  ...          [SPOT]
1712     FTMAUD  ...          [SPOT]
1713     FTMBRL  ...          [SPOT]
1714   SCRTBUSD  ...          [SPOT]
[1715 rows x 17 columns]
```

Then you can [save it to excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) if you needed to:

```
df.to_excel('binance.xlsx')
```

Comment: I think you don't need to use for loop.


symbols = client.get_exchange_info()


symbols = pd.DataFrame(symbols["symbols"])["symbol"]

Answer (score 1):

```
from binance.client import Client
import pandas as pd

client = Client('api_key', 'api_secret')

pairs = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(client.get_all_tickers())['symbol'].to_list()

pairs_sorted = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(client.get_all_tickers()).sort_values(by=['symbol'], ascending=True)['symbol'].to_list()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to update the code provided by Emad above.

```
from binance.client import Client
import pandas as pd

api_key = 'Your Api Key'
api_secret = 'Your Secret Key'

client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
symbols = client.get_exchange_info()
df = pd.DataFrame(symbols['symbols'])

li = []

for index, data in df.iterrows():
    if data['isMarginTradingAllowed'] == True:
        li.append(data['symbol'])

fdf = pd.DataFrame(li)
fdf.to_excel('Margin Trading Pairs.xlsx', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your are looking all symbol for only USDT Future Market then use this

First use this command to install pyhon biance

```
pip install python-binance
```

```py
from binance.client import Client

client = Client()
exchange_info = client.futures_exchange_info()
usdt = set()
for s in exchange_info['symbols']:
    if s['symbol'].endswith('USDT'):
        usdt.add(s['symbol'])
print(usdt)
print(len(usdt))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
int symbol_toplam = jsonx[6].Size();

//for(int i = jsonx.Size()-1; i>=0; i--){

for (int y=0;y<=symbol_toplam;y++) {

//for(int t = 0;t<=0;t++) {

// symbols 6 

if ( jsonx[6][y][0].ToStr() != "" ) {

if ( jsonx[6][y][0].ToStr() == symbol_coin ) {

Print("Min Lot:",jsonx[6][y][0].ToStr(),"=",jsonx[6][y][21][1][3].ToStr());
min_lot=jsonx[6][y][21][1][3].ToDbl();
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
import _     from 'lodash'
import fsp   from 'fs/promises'

const get_coins = (symbols) => {
    const coins = []
    symbols.forEach(symbol=>{
        coins.push(symbol.baseAsset)
        coins.push(symbol.quoteAsset)
    })
    return _.uniq(coins)
}

fetch("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo")
    .then(response=>response.json())
    .then(json=> get_coins(json.symbols))
    .then(coins=>fsp.writeFile('coins.txt',  JSON.stringify(coins)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a gist for this @https://gist.github.com/Milimeter/2cea803b4fd87dae5e0741c2018359de.

This is not the top 100 symbol but all the symbol combination returned from

> GET /api/v1/exchangeInfo

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who need it, I past list of pairs crypto eg. USDT, EUR, BTC, ETH here: [List of Binance traiding pairs](https://kurzovnilistek.eu/binance-usdt-eur-btc-eth-pairs-list/)

Answer (score 0):

1. As Nick Friskel and Gustavo E. Hennemann says you can check [docs page](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md)
2. `curl -X GET "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo" -o symbols.json`
3. Paste content of the symbols.json file to the [json parser service](https://jsonformatter.org/json-parser)
4. And then filter it by query `symbols[*].symbol` like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sn7e1.png)
5. Result

   ```
   ["ETHBTC","LTCBTC","BNBBTC","NEOBTC","QTUMETH","EOSETH","SNTETH","BNTETH","BCCBTC","GASBTC","BNBETH","BTCUSDT","ETHUSDT","HSRBTC","OAXETH","DNTETH","MCOETH","ICNETH","MCOBTC","WTCBTC","WTCETH","LRCBTC","LRCETH","QTUMBTC","YOYOBTC","OMGBTC","OMGETH","ZRXBTC","ZRXETH","STRATBTC","STRATETH","SNGLSBTC","SNGLSETH","BQXBTC","BQXETH","KNCBTC","KNCETH","FUNBTC","FUNETH","SNMBTC","SNMETH","NEOETH","IOTABTC","IOTAETH","LINKBTC","LINKETH","XVGBTC","XVGETH","SALTBTC","SALTETH","MDABTC","MDAETH","MTLBTC","MTLETH","SUBBTC","SUBETH","EOSBTC","SNTBTC","ETCETH","ETCBTC","MTHBTC","MTHETH","ENGBTC","ENGETH","DNTBTC","ZECBTC","ZECETH","BNTBTC","ASTBTC","ASTETH","DASHBTC","DASHETH","OAXBTC","ICNBTC","BTGBTC","BTGETH","EVXBTC","EVXETH","REQBTC","REQETH","VIBBTC","VIBETH","HSRETH","TRXBTC","TRXETH","POWRBTC","POWRETH","ARKBTC","ARKETH","YOYOETH","XRPBTC","XRPETH","MODBTC","MODETH","ENJBTC","ENJETH","STORJBTC","STORJETH","BNBUSDT","VENBNB","YOYOBNB","POWRBNB","VENBTC","VENETH","KMDBTC","KMDETH","NULSBNB","RCNBTC","RCNETH","RCNBNB","NULSBTC","NULSETH","RDNBTC","RDNETH","RDNBNB","XMRBTC","XMRETH","DLTBNB","WTCBNB","DLTBTC","DLTETH","AMBBTC","AMBETH","AMBBNB","BCCETH","BCCUSDT","BCCBNB","BATBTC","BATETH","BATBNB","BCPTBTC","BCPTETH","BCPTBNB","ARNBTC","ARNETH","GVTBTC","GVTETH","CDTBTC","CDTETH","GXSBTC","GXSETH","NEOUSDT","NEOBNB","POEBTC","POEETH","QSPBTC","QSPETH","QSPBNB","BTSBTC","BTSETH","BTSBNB","XZCBTC","XZCETH","XZCBNB","LSKBTC","LSKETH","LSKBNB","TNTBTC","TNTETH","FUELBTC","FUELETH","MANABTC","MANAETH","BCDBTC","BCDETH","DGDBTC","DGDETH","IOTABNB","ADXBTC","ADXETH","ADXBNB","ADABTC","ADAETH","PPTBTC","PPTETH","CMTBTC","CMTETH","CMTBNB","XLMBTC","XLMETH","XLMBNB","CNDBTC","CNDETH","CNDBNB","LENDBTC","LENDETH","WABIBTC","WABIETH","WABIBNB","LTCETH","LTCUSDT","LTCBNB","TNBBTC","TNBETH","WAVESBTC","WAVESETH","WAVESBNB","GTOBTC","GTOETH","GTOBNB","ICXBTC","ICXETH","ICXBNB","OSTBTC","OSTETH","OSTBNB","ELFBTC","ELFETH","AIONBTC","AIONETH","AIONBNB","NEBLBTC","NEBLBNB","BRDBTC","BRDETH","BRDBNB","MCOBNB","EDOBTC","EDOETH","WINGSBTC","WINGSETH","NAVBTC","NAVETH","NAVBNB","LUNBTC","LUNETH","TRIGBTC","TRIGETH","TRIGBNB","APPCBTC","APPCETH","APPCBNB","VIBEBTC","VIBEETH","RLCBTC","RLCETH","RLCBNB","INSBTC","INSETH","PIVXBTC","PIVXBNB","IOSTBTC","IOSTETH","CHATBTC","CHATETH","STEEMBTC","STEEMETH","STEEMBNB","NANOBTC","NANOETH","NANOBNB","VIABTC","VIAETH","VIABNB","BLZBTC","BLZETH","BLZBNB","AEBTC","AEETH","AEBNB","RPXBTC","RPXETH","RPXBNB","NCASHBTC","NCASHETH","NCASHBNB","POABTC","POAETH","POABNB","ZILBTC","ZILETH","ZILBNB","ONTBTC","ONTETH","ONTBNB","STORMBTC","STORMETH","STORMBNB","QTUMBNB","QTUMUSDT","XEMBTC","XEMETH","XEMBNB","WANBTC","WANETH","WANBNB","WPRBTC","WPRETH","QLCBTC","QLCETH","SYSBTC","SYSETH","SYSBNB","QLCBNB","GRSBTC","GRSETH","ADAUSDT","ADABNB","CLOAKBTC","CLOAKETH","GNTBTC","GNTETH","GNTBNB","LOOMBTC","LOOMETH","LOOMBNB","XRPUSDT","BCNBTC","BCNETH","BCNBNB","REPBTC","REPBNB","BTCTUSD","TUSDBTC","ETHTUSD","TUSDETH","TUSDBNB","ZENBTC","ZENETH","ZENBNB","SKYBTC","SKYETH","SKYBNB","EOSUSDT","EOSBNB","CVCBTC","CVCETH","CVCBNB","THETABTC","THETAETH","THETABNB","XRPBNB","TUSDUSDT","IOTAUSDT","XLMUSDT","IOTXBTC","IOTXETH","QKCBTC","QKCETH","AGIBTC","AGIETH","AGIBNB","NXSBTC","NXSETH","NXSBNB","ENJBNB","DATABTC","DATAETH","ONTUSDT","TRXBNB","TRXUSDT","ETCUSDT","ETCBNB","ICXUSDT","SCBTC","SCETH","NPXSBTC","NPXSETH","VENUSDT","KEYBTC","KEYETH","NASBTC","NASETH","NASBNB","MFTBTC","MFTETH","MFTBNB","DENTBTC","DENTETH","ARDRBTC","ARDRETH","ARDRBNB","NULSUSDT","HOTBTC","HOTETH","VETBTC","VETETH","VETUSDT","VETBNB","DOCKBTC","DOCKETH","POLYBTC","POLYBNB","PHXBTC","PHXETH","PHXBNB","HCBTC","HCETH","GOBTC","GOBNB","PAXBTC","PAXBNB","PAXUSDT","PAXETH","RVNBTC","DCRBTC","DCRBNB","USDCBNB","MITHBTC","MITHBNB","BCHABCBTC","BCHSVBTC","BCHABCUSDT","BCHSVUSDT","BNBPAX","BTCPAX","ETHPAX","XRPPAX","EOSPAX","XLMPAX","RENBTC","RENBNB","BNBTUSD","XRPTUSD","EOSTUSD","XLMTUSD","BNBUSDC","BTCUSDC","ETHUSDC","XRPUSDC","EOSUSDC","XLMUSDC","USDCUSDT","ADATUSD","TRXTUSD","NEOTUSD","TRXXRP","XZCXRP","PAXTUSD","USDCTUSD","USDCPAX","LINKUSDT","LINKTUSD","LINKPAX","LINKUSDC","WAVESUSDT","WAVESTUSD","WAVESPAX","WAVESUSDC","BCHABCTUSD","BCHABCPAX","BCHABCUSDC","BCHSVTUSD","BCHSVPAX","BCHSVUSDC","LTCTUSD","LTCPAX","LTCUSDC","TRXPAX","TRXUSDC","BTTBTC","BTTBNB","BTTUSDT","BNBUSDS","BTCUSDS","USDSUSDT","USDSPAX","USDSTUSD","USDSUSDC","BTTPAX","BTTTUSD","BTTUSDC","ONGBNB","ONGBTC","ONGUSDT","HOTBNB","HOTUSDT","ZILUSDT","ZRXBNB","ZRXUSDT","FETBNB","FETBTC","FETUSDT","BATUSDT","XMRBNB","XMRUSDT","ZECBNB","ZECUSDT","ZECPAX","ZECTUSD","ZECUSDC","IOSTUSDT","CELRBNB","CELRBTC","CELRUSDT","ADAPAX","ADAUSDC","NEOPAX","NEOUSDC","DASHBNB","DASHUSDT","NANOUSDT","OMGBNB","OMGUSDT","THETAUSDT","ENJUSDT","MITHUSDT","MATICBNB","MATICBTC","MATICUSDT","ATOMBNB","ATOMBTC","ATOMUSDT","ATOMUSDC","ATOMPAX","ATOMTUSD","ETCUSDC","ETCPAX","ETCTUSD","BATUSDC","BATPAX","BATTUSD","PHBBNB","PHBBTC","PHBUSDC","PHBTUSD","PHBPAX","TFUELBNB","TFUELBTC","TFUELUSDT","TFUELUSDC","TFUELTUSD","TFUELPAX","ONEBNB","ONEBTC","ONEUSDT","ONETUSD","ONEPAX","ONEUSDC","FTMBNB","FTMBTC","FTMUSDT","FTMTUSD","FTMPAX","FTMUSDC","BTCBBTC","BCPTTUSD","BCPTPAX","BCPTUSDC","ALGOBNB","ALGOBTC","ALGOUSDT","ALGOTUSD","ALGOPAX","ALGOUSDC","USDSBUSDT","USDSBUSDS","GTOUSDT","GTOPAX","GTOTUSD","GTOUSDC","ERDBNB","ERDBTC","ERDUSDT","ERDPAX","ERDUSDC","DOGEBNB","DOGEBTC","DOGEUSDT","DOGEPAX","DOGEUSDC","DUSKBNB","DUSKBTC","DUSKUSDT","DUSKUSDC","DUSKPAX","BGBPUSDC","ANKRBNB","ANKRBTC","ANKRUSDT","ANKRTUSD","ANKRPAX","ANKRUSDC","ONTPAX","ONTUSDC","WINBNB","WINBTC","WINUSDT","WINUSDC","COSBNB","COSBTC","COSUSDT","TUSDBTUSD","NPXSUSDT","NPXSUSDC","COCOSBNB","COCOSBTC","COCOSUSDT","MTLUSDT","TOMOBNB","TOMOBTC","TOMOUSDT","TOMOUSDC","PERLBNB","PERLBTC","PERLUSDC","PERLUSDT","DENTUSDT","MFTUSDT","KEYUSDT","STORMUSDT","DOCKUSDT","WANUSDT","FUNUSDT","CVCUSDT","BTTTRX","WINTRX","CHZBNB","CHZBTC","CHZUSDT","BANDBNB","BANDBTC","BANDUSDT","BNBBUSD","BTCBUSD","BUSDUSDT","BEAMBNB","BEAMBTC","BEAMUSDT","XTZBNB","XTZBTC","XTZUSDT","RENUSDT","RVNUSDT","HCUSDT","HBARBNB","HBARBTC","HBARUSDT","NKNBNB","NKNBTC","NKNUSDT","XRPBUSD","ETHBUSD","BCHABCBUSD","LTCBUSD","LINKBUSD","ETCBUSD","STXBNB","STXBTC","STXUSDT","KAVABNB","KAVABTC","KAVAUSDT","BUSDNGN","BNBNGN","BTCNGN","ARPABNB","ARPABTC","ARPAUSDT","TRXBUSD","EOSBUSD","IOTXUSDT","RLCUSDT","MCOUSDT","XLMBUSD","ADABUSD","CTXCBNB","CTXCBTC","CTXCUSDT","BCHBNB","BCHBTC","BCHUSDT","BCHUSDC","BCHTUSD","BCHPAX","BCHBUSD","BTCRUB","ETHRUB","XRPRUB","BNBRUB","TROYBNB","TROYBTC","TROYUSDT","BUSDRUB","QTUMBUSD","VETBUSD","VITEBNB","VITEBTC","VITEUSDT","FTTBNB","FTTBTC","FTTUSDT","BTCTRY","BNBTRY","BUSDTRY","ETHTRY","XRPTRY","USDTTRY","USDTRUB","BTCEUR","ETHEUR","BNBEUR","XRPEUR","EURBUSD","EURUSDT","OGNBNB","OGNBTC","OGNUSDT","DREPBNB","DREPBTC","DREPUSDT","BULLUSDT","BULLBUSD","BEARUSDT","BEARBUSD","ETHBULLUSDT","ETHBULLBUSD","ETHBEARUSDT","ETHBEARBUSD","TCTBNB","TCTBTC","TCTUSDT","WRXBNB","WRXBTC","WRXUSDT","ICXBUSD","BTSUSDT","BTSBUSD","LSKUSDT","BNTUSDT","BNTBUSD","LTOBNB","LTOBTC","LTOUSDT","ATOMBUSD","DASHBUSD","NEOBUSD","WAVESBUSD","XTZBUSD","EOSBULLUSDT","EOSBULLBUSD","EOSBEARUSDT","EOSBEARBUSD","XRPBULLUSDT","XRPBULLBUSD","XRPBEARUSDT","XRPBEARBUSD","BATBUSD","ENJBUSD","NANOBUSD","ONTBUSD","RVNBUSD","STRATBUSD","STRATBNB","STRATUSDT","AIONBUSD","AIONUSDT","MBLBNB","MBLBTC","MBLUSDT","COTIBNB","COTIBTC","COTIUSDT","ALGOBUSD","BTTBUSD","TOMOBUSD","XMRBUSD","ZECBUSD","BNBBULLUSDT","BNBBULLBUSD","BNBBEARUSDT","BNBBEARBUSD","STPTBNB","STPTBTC","STPTUSDT","BTCZAR","ETHZAR","BNBZAR","USDTZAR","BUSDZAR","BTCBKRW","ETHBKRW","BNBBKRW","WTCUSDT","DATABUSD","DATAUSDT","XZCUSDT","SOLBNB","SOLBTC","SOLUSDT","SOLBUSD","BTCIDRT","BNBIDRT","USDTIDRT","BUSDIDRT","CTSIBTC","CTSIUSDT","CTSIBNB","CTSIBUSD","HIVEBNB","HIVEBTC","HIVEUSDT","CHRBNB","CHRBTC","CHRUSDT","BTCUPUSDT","BTCDOWNUSDT","GXSUSDT","ARDRUSDT","ERDBUSD","LENDUSDT","HBARBUSD","MATICBUSD","WRXBUSD","ZILBUSD","MDTBNB","MDTBTC","MDTUSDT","STMXBTC","STMXETH","STMXUSDT","KNCBUSD","KNCUSDT","REPBUSD","REPUSDT","LRCBUSD","LRCUSDT","IQBNB","IQBUSD","PNTBTC","PNTUSDT","BTCGBP","ETHGBP","XRPGBP","BNBGBP","GBPBUSD","DGBBTC","DGBBUSD","BTCUAH","USDTUAH","COMPBTC","COMPBNB","COMPBUSD","COMPUSDT","BTCBIDR","ETHBIDR","BNBBIDR","BUSDBIDR","USDTBIDR","BKRWUSDT","BKRWBUSD","SCUSDT","ZENUSDT","SXPBTC","SXPBNB","SXPBUSD","SNXBTC","SNXBNB","SNXBUSD","SNXUSDT","ETHUPUSDT","ETHDOWNUSDT","ADAUPUSDT","ADADOWNUSDT","LINKUPUSDT","LINKDOWNUSDT","VTHOBNB","VTHOBUSD","VTHOUSDT","DCRBUSD","DGBUSDT","GBPUSDT","STORJBUSD","SXPUSDT","IRISBNB","IRISBTC","IRISBUSD","MKRBNB","MKRBTC","MKRUSDT","MKRBUSD","DAIBNB","DAIBTC","DAIUSDT","DAIBUSD","RUNEBNB","RUNEBTC","RUNEBUSD","MANABUSD","DOGEBUSD","LENDBUSD","ZRXBUSD","DCRUSDT","STORJUSDT","XRPBKRW","ADABKRW","BTCAUD","ETHAUD","AUDBUSD","FIOBNB","FIOBTC","FIOBUSD","BNBUPUSDT","BNBDOWNUSDT","XTZUPUSDT","XTZDOWNUSDT","AVABNB","AVABTC","AVABUSD","USDTBKRW","BUSDBKRW","IOTABUSD","MANAUSDT","XRPAUD","BNBAUD","AUDUSDT","BALBNB","BALBTC","BALBUSD","YFIBNB","YFIBTC","YFIBUSD","YFIUSDT","BLZBUSD","KMDBUSD","BALUSDT","BLZUSDT","IRISUSDT","KMDUSDT","BTCDAI","ETHDAI","BNBDAI","USDTDAI","BUSDDAI","JSTBNB","JSTBTC","JSTBUSD","JSTUSDT","SRMBNB","SRMBTC","SRMBUSD","SRMUSDT","ANTBNB","ANTBTC","ANTBUSD","ANTUSDT","CRVBNB","CRVBTC","CRVBUSD","CRVUSDT","SANDBNB","SANDBTC","SANDUSDT","SANDBUSD","OCEANBNB","OCEANBTC","OCEANBUSD","OCEANUSDT","NMRBTC","NMRBUSD","NMRUSDT","DOTBNB","DOTBTC","DOTBUSD","DOTUSDT","LUNABNB","LUNABTC","LUNABUSD","LUNAUSDT","IDEXBTC","IDEXBUSD","RSRBNB","RSRBTC","RSRBUSD","RSRUSDT","PAXGBNB","PAXGBTC","PAXGBUSD","PAXGUSDT","WNXMBNB","WNXMBTC","WNXMBUSD","WNXMUSDT","TRBBNB","TRBBTC","TRBBUSD","TRBUSDT","ETHNGN","DOTBIDR","LINKAUD","SXPAUD","BZRXBNB","BZRXBTC","BZRXBUSD","BZRXUSDT","WBTCBTC","WBTCETH","SUSHIBNB","SUSHIBTC","SUSHIBUSD","SUSHIUSDT","YFIIBNB","YFIIBTC","YFIIBUSD","YFIIUSDT","KSMBNB","KSMBTC","KSMBUSD","KSMUSDT","EGLDBNB","EGLDBTC","EGLDBUSD","EGLDUSDT","DIABNB","DIABTC","DIABUSD","DIAUSDT","RUNEUSDT","FIOUSDT","UMABTC","UMAUSDT","EOSUPUSDT","EOSDOWNUSDT","TRXUPUSDT","TRXDOWNUSDT","XRPUPUSDT","XRPDOWNUSDT","DOTUPUSDT","DOTDOWNUSDT","SRMBIDR","ONEBIDR","LINKTRY","USDTNGN","BELBNB","BELBTC","BELBUSD","BELUSDT","WINGBNB","WINGBTC","SWRVBNB","SWRVBUSD","WINGBUSD","WINGUSDT","LTCUPUSDT","LTCDOWNUSDT","LENDBKRW","SXPEUR","CREAMBNB","CREAMBUSD","UNIBNB","UNIBTC","UNIBUSD","UNIUSDT","NBSBTC","NBSUSDT","OXTBTC","OXTUSDT","SUNBTC","SUNUSDT","AVAXBNB","AVAXBTC","AVAXBUSD","AVAXUSDT","HNTBTC","HNTUSDT","BAKEBNB","BURGERBNB","SXPBIDR","LINKBKRW","FLMBNB","FLMBTC","FLMBUSD","FLMUSDT","SCRTBTC","SCRTETH","CAKEBNB","CAKEBUSD","SPARTABNB","UNIUPUSDT","UNIDOWNUSDT","ORNBTC","ORNUSDT","TRXNGN","SXPTRY","UTKBTC","UTKUSDT","XVSBNB","XVSBTC","XVSBUSD","XVSUSDT","ALPHABNB","ALPHABTC","ALPHABUSD","ALPHAUSDT","VIDTBTC","VIDTBUSD","AAVEBNB","BTCBRL","USDTBRL","AAVEBTC","AAVEETH","AAVEBUSD","AAVEUSDT","AAVEBKRW","NEARBNB","NEARBTC","NEARBUSD","NEARUSDT","SXPUPUSDT","SXPDOWNUSDT","DOTBKRW","SXPGBP","FILBNB","FILBTC","FILBUSD","FILUSDT","FILUPUSDT","FILDOWNUSDT","YFIUPUSDT","YFIDOWNUSDT","INJBNB","INJBTC","INJBUSD","INJUSDT","AERGOBTC","AERGOBUSD","LINKEUR","ONEBUSD","EASYETH","AUDIOBTC","AUDIOBUSD","AUDIOUSDT","CTKBNB","CTKBTC","CTKBUSD","CTKUSDT","BCHUPUSDT","BCHDOWNUSDT","BOTBTC","BOTBUSD","ETHBRL","DOTEUR","AKROBTC","AKROUSDT","KP3RBNB","KP3RBUSD","AXSBNB","AXSBTC","AXSBUSD","AXSUSDT","HARDBNB","HARDBTC","HARDBUSD","HARDUSDT","BNBBRL","LTCEUR","RENBTCBTC","RENBTCETH","DNTBUSD","DNTUSDT","SLPETH","ADAEUR","LTCNGN","CVPETH","CVPBUSD","STRAXBTC","STRAXETH","STRAXBUSD","STRAXUSDT","FORBTC","FORBUSD","UNFIBNB","UNFIBTC","UNFIBUSD","UNFIUSDT","FRONTETH","FRONTBUSD","BCHABUSD","ROSEBTC","ROSEBUSD","ROSEUSDT","AVAXTRY","BUSDBRL","AVAUSDT","SYSBUSD","XEMUSDT","HEGICETH","HEGICBUSD","AAVEUPUSDT","AAVEDOWNUSDT","PROMBNB","PROMBUSD","XRPBRL","XRPNGN","SKLBTC","SKLBUSD","SKLUSDT","BCHEUR","YFIEUR","ZILBIDR","SUSDBTC","SUSDETH","SUSDUSDT","COVERETH","COVERBUSD","GLMBTC","GLMETH","GHSTETH","GHSTBUSD","SUSHIUPUSDT","SUSHIDOWNUSDT","XLMUPUSDT","XLMDOWNUSDT","LINKBRL","LINKNGN","LTCRUB","TRXTRY","XLMEUR","DFETH","DFBUSD","GRTBTC","GRTETH","GRTUSDT","JUVBTC","JUVBUSD","JUVUSDT","PSGBTC","PSGBUSD","PSGUSDT","BUSDBVND","USDTBVND","1INCHBTC","1INCHUSDT","REEFBTC","REEFUSDT","OGBTC","OGUSDT","ATMBTC","ATMUSDT","ASRBTC","ASRUSDT","CELOBTC","CELOUSDT","RIFBTC","RIFUSDT","CHZTRY","XLMTRY","LINKGBP","GRTEUR","BTCSTBTC","BTCSTBUSD","BTCSTUSDT","TRUBTC","TRUBUSD","TRUUSDT","DEXEETH","DEXEBUSD","EOSEUR","LTCBRL","USDCBUSD","TUSDBUSD","PAXBUSD","CKBBTC","CKBBUSD","CKBUSDT","TWTBTC","TWTBUSD","TWTUSDT","FIROBTC","FIROETH","FIROUSDT","BETHETH","DOGEEUR","DOGETRY","DOGEAUD","DOGEBRL","DOTNGN","PROSETH","LITBTC","LITBUSD","LITUSDT","BTCVAI","BUSDVAI","SFPBTC","SFPBUSD","SFPUSDT","DOGEGBP","DOTTRY","FXSBTC","FXSBUSD","DODOBTC","DODOBUSD","DODOUSDT","FRONTBTC","EASYBTC","CAKEBTC","CAKEUSDT","BAKEBUSD","UFTETH","UFTBUSD","1INCHBUSD","BANDBUSD","GRTBUSD","IOSTBUSD","OMGBUSD","REEFBUSD","ACMBTC","ACMBUSD","ACMUSDT","AUCTIONBTC","AUCTIONBUSD","PHABTC","PHABUSD","DOTGBP","ADATRY","ADABRL","ADAGBP","TVKBTC","TVKBUSD","BADGERBTC","BADGERBUSD","BADGERUSDT","FISBTC","FISBUSD","FISUSDT","DOTBRL","ADAAUD","HOTTRY","EGLDEUR","OMBTC","OMBUSD","OMUSDT","PONDBTC","PONDBUSD","PONDUSDT","DEGOBTC","DEGOBUSD","DEGOUSDT","AVAXEUR","BTTTRY","CHZBRL","UNIEUR","ALICEBTC","ALICEBUSD","ALICEUSDT","CHZBUSD","CHZEUR","CHZGBP","BIFIBNB","BIFIBUSD","LINABTC","LINABUSD","LINAUSDT","ADARUB","ENJBRL","ENJEUR","MATICEUR","NEOTRY","PERPBTC","PERPBUSD","PERPUSDT","RAMPBTC","RAMPBUSD","RAMPUSDT","SUPERBTC","SUPERBUSD","SUPERUSDT","CFXBTC","CFXBUSD","CFXUSDT","ENJGBP","EOSTRY","LTCGBP","LUNAEUR","RVNTRY","THETAEUR","XVGBUSD","EPSBTC","EPSBUSD","EPSUSDT","AUTOBTC","AUTOBUSD","AUTOUSDT","TKOBTC","TKOBIDR","TKOBUSD","TKOUSDT","PUNDIXETH","PUNDIXUSDT","BTTBRL","BTTEUR","HOTEUR","WINEUR","TLMBTC","TLMBUSD","TLMUSDT","1INCHUPUSDT","1INCHDOWNUSDT","BTGBUSD","BTGUSDT","HOTBUSD","BNBUAH","ONTTRY","VETEUR","VETGBP","WINBRL","MIRBTC","MIRBUSD","MIRUSDT","BARBTC","BARBUSD","BARUSDT","FORTHBTC","FORTHBUSD","FORTHUSDT","CAKEGBP","DOGERUB","HOTBRL","WRXEUR","BAKEUSDT","BURGERBUSD","BURGERUSDT","SLPBUSD","SLPUSDT","TRXAUD","TRXEUR","VETTRY","SHIBUSDT","SHIBBUSD","ICPBTC","ICPBNB","ICPBUSD","ICPUSDT","SHIBEUR","SHIBRUB","ETCEUR","ETCBRL","DOGEBIDR","ARBTC","ARBNB","ARBUSD","ARUSDT","POLSBTC","POLSBNB","POLSBUSD","POLSUSDT","MDXBTC","MDXBNB","MDXBUSD","MDXUSDT","MASKBNB","MASKBUSD","MASKUSDT","LPTBTC","LPTBNB","LPTBUSD","LPTUSDT","ETHUAH","MATICBRL","SOLEUR","SHIBBRL","AGIXBTC","ICPEUR","MATICGBP","SHIBTRY","MATICBIDR","MATICRUB","NUBTC","NUBNB","NUBUSD","NUUSDT","XVGUSDT","RLCBUSD","CELRBUSD","ATMBUSD","ZENBUSD","FTMBUSD","THETABUSD","WINBUSD","KAVABUSD","XEMBUSD","ATABTC","ATABNB","ATABUSD","ATAUSDT","GTCBTC","GTCBNB","GTCBUSD","GTCUSDT","TORNBTC","TORNBNB","TORNBUSD","TORNUSDT","MATICTRY","ETCGBP","SOLGBP","BAKEBTC","COTIBUSD","KEEPBTC","KEEPBNB","KEEPBUSD","KEEPUSDT","SOLTRY","RUNEGBP","SOLBRL","SCBUSD","CHRBUSD","STMXBUSD","HNTBUSD","FTTBUSD","DOCKBUSD","ADABIDR","ERNBNB","ERNBUSD","ERNUSDT","KLAYBTC","KLAYBNB","KLAYBUSD","KLAYUSDT","RUNEEUR","MATICAUD","DOTRUB","UTKBUSD","IOTXBUSD","PHAUSDT","SOLRUB","RUNEAUD","BUSDUAH","BONDBTC","BONDBNB","BONDBUSD","BONDUSDT","MLNBTC","MLNBNB","MLNBUSD","MLNUSDT","GRTTRY","CAKEBRL","ICPRUB","DOTAUD","AAVEBRL","EOSAUD","DEXEUSDT","LTOBUSD","ADXBUSD","QUICKBTC","QUICKBNB","QUICKBUSD","C98USDT","C98BUSD","C98BNB","C98BTC","CLVBTC","CLVBNB","CLVBUSD","CLVUSDT","QNTBTC","QNTBNB","QNTBUSD","QNTUSDT","FLOWBTC","FLOWBNB","FLOWBUSD","FLOWUSDT","XECBUSD","AXSBRL","AXSAUD","TVKUSDT","MINABTC","MINABNB","MINABUSD","MINAUSDT","RAYBNB","RAYBUSD","RAYUSDT","FARMBTC","FARMBNB","FARMBUSD","FARMUSDT","ALPACABTC","ALPACABNB","ALPACABUSD","ALPACAUSDT","TLMTRY","QUICKUSDT","ORNBUSD","MBOXBTC","MBOXBNB","MBOXBUSD","MBOXUSDT","VGXBTC","VGXETH","FORUSDT","REQUSDT","GHSTUSDT","TRURUB","FISBRL","WAXPUSDT","WAXPBUSD","WAXPBNB","WAXPBTC","TRIBEBTC","TRIBEBNB","TRIBEBUSD","TRIBEUSDT","GNOUSDT","GNOBUSD","GNOBNB","GNOBTC","ARPATRY","PROMBTC","MTLBUSD","OGNBUSD","XECUSDT","C98BRL","SOLAUD","XRPBIDR","POLYBUSD","ELFUSDT","DYDXUSDT","DYDXBUSD","DYDXBNB","DYDXBTC","ELFBUSD","POLYUSDT","IDEXUSDT","VIDTUSDT","SOLBIDR","BTCUSDP","ETHUSDP","BNBUSDP","USDPBUSD","USDPUSDT","GALAUSDT","GALABUSD","GALABNB","GALABTC","FTMBIDR","ALGOBIDR","CAKEAUD","KSMAUD","WAVESRUB","SUNBUSD","ILVUSDT","ILVBUSD","ILVBNB","ILVBTC","RENBUSD","YGGUSDT","YGGBUSD","YGGBNB","YGGBTC","STXBUSD","SYSUSDT","DFUSDT","SOLUSDC","ARPARUB","LTCUAH","FETBUSD","ARPABUSD","LSKBUSD","AVAXBIDR","ALICEBIDR","FIDAUSDT","FIDABUSD","FIDABNB","FIDABTC","DENTBUSD","FRONTUSDT","CVPUSDT","AGLDBTC","AGLDBNB","AGLDBUSD","AGLDUSDT","RADBTC","RADBNB","RADBUSD","RADUSDT","UNIAUD","HIVEBUSD","STPTBUSD","BETABTC","BETABNB","BETABUSD","BETAUSDT","SHIBAUD","RAREBTC","RAREBNB","RAREBUSD","RAREUSDT","AVAXBRL","AVAXAUD","LUNAAUD","TROYBUSD","AXSETH","FTMETH","SOLETH","SSVBTC","SSVETH","LAZIOTRY","LAZIOEUR","LAZIOBTC","LAZIOUSDT","CHESSBTC","CHESSBNB","CHESSBUSD","CHESSUSDT","FTMAUD","FTMBRL","SCRTBUSD","ADXUSDT","AUCTIONUSDT","CELOBUSD","FTMRUB","NUAUD","NURUB","REEFTRY","REEFBIDR","SHIBDOGE","DARUSDT","DARBUSD","DARBNB","DARBTC","BNXBTC","BNXBNB","BNXBUSD","BNXUSDT","RGTUSDT","RGTBTC","RGTBUSD","RGTBNB","LAZIOBUSD","OXTBUSD","MANATRY","ALGORUB","SHIBUAH","LUNABIDR","AUDUSDC","MOVRBTC","MOVRBNB","MOVRBUSD","MOVRUSDT","CITYBTC","CITYBNB","CITYBUSD","CITYUSDT","ENSBTC","ENSBNB","ENSBUSD","ENSUSDT","SANDETH","DOTETH","MATICETH","ANKRBUSD","SANDTRY","MANABRL","KP3RUSDT","QIUSDT","QIBUSD","QIBNB","QIBTC","PORTOBTC","PORTOUSDT","PORTOTRY","PORTOEUR","POWRUSDT","POWRBUSD","AVAXETH","SLPTRY","FISTRY","LRCTRY","CHRETH","FISBIDR","VGXUSDT","GALAETH","JASMYUSDT","JASMYBUSD","JASMYBNB","JASMYBTC","AMPBTC","AMPBNB","AMPBUSD","AMPUSDT","PLABTC","PLABNB","PLABUSD","PLAUSDT","PYRBTC","PYRBUSD","PYRUSDT","RNDRBTC","RNDRUSDT","RNDRBUSD","ALCXBTC","ALCXBUSD","ALCXUSDT","SANTOSBTC","SANTOSUSDT","SANTOSBRL","SANTOSTRY","MCBTC","MCBUSD","MCUSDT","BELTRY","COCOSBUSD","DENTTRY","ENJTRY","NEORUB","SANDAUD","SLPBIDR","ANYBTC","ANYBUSD","ANYUSDT","BICOBTC","BICOBUSD","BICOUSDT","FLUXBTC","FLUXBUSD","FLUXUSDT","ALICETRY","FXSUSDT","GALABRL","GALATRY","LUNATRY","REQBUSD","SANDBRL","MANABIDR","SANDBIDR","VOXELBTC","VOXELBNB","VOXELBUSD","VOXELUSDT","COSBUSD","CTXCBUSD","FTMTRY","MANABNB","MINATRY","XTZTRY","HIGHBTC","HIGHBUSD","HIGHUSDT","CVXBTC","CVXBUSD","CVXUSDT","PEOPLEBTC","PEOPLEBUSD","PEOPLEUSDT","OOKIBUSD","OOKIUSDT","COCOSTRY","GXSBNB","LINKBNB","LUNAETH","MDTBUSD","NULSBUSD","SPELLBTC","SPELLUSDT","SPELLBUSD","USTBTC","USTBUSD","USTUSDT","JOEBTC","JOEBUSD","JOEUSDT","ATOMETH","DUSKBUSD","EGLDETH","ICPETH","LUNABRL","LUNAUST","NEARETH","ROSEBNB","VOXELETH","ALICEBNB","ATOMTRY","ETHUST","GALAAUD","LRCBNB","ONEETH","OOKIBNB","ACHBTC","ACHBUSD","ACHUSDT","IMXBTC","IMXBUSD","IMXUSDT","GLMRBTC","GLMRBUSD","GLMRUSDT","ATOMBIDR","DYDXETH","FARMETH","FORBNB","ICPTRY","JASMYETH","LINABNB","OOKIETH","ROSEETH","UMABUSD","UNIETH","XTZETH","LOKABTC","LOKABNB","LOKABUSD","LOKAUSDT","ATOMBRL","BNBUST","CRVETH","HIGHBNB","NEARRUB","ROSETRY","SCRTUSDT","API3BTC","API3BUSD","API3USDT","BTTCUSDT","BTTCUSDC","BTTCTRY","ACABTC","ACABUSD","ACAUSDT","ANCBTC","ANCBUSD","ANCUSDT","BDOTDOT","XNOBTC","XNOETH","XNOBUSD","XNOUSDT","COSTRY","KAVAETH","MCBNB","ONETRY","WOOBTC","WOOBNB","WOOBUSD","WOOUSDT","CELRETH","PEOPLEBNB","SLPBNB","SPELLBNB","SPELLTRY","TFUELBUSD","AXSTRY","DARTRY","NEARTRY","IDEXBNB","ALPINEEUR","ALPINETRY","ALPINEUSDT","ALPINEBTC","TUSDT","TBUSD","API3BNB","BETAETH","INJTRY","TLMBNB","ASTRBUSD","ASTRUSDT","API3TRY","GLMRBNB","MBOXTRY","GMTBTC","GMTBNB","GMTBUSD","GMTUSDT","ANCBNB","ATOMEUR","GALAEUR","KSMETH","UMATRY","KDABTC","KDABUSD","KDAUSDT","APEUSDT","APEBUSD","APEBTC","ALPINEBUSD","LUNAGBP","NEAREUR","TWTTRY","WAVESEUR","APEEUR","APEGBP","APETRY","BSWUSDT","BSWBUSD","BSWBNB","APEBNB","GMTBRL","GMTETH","JASMYTRY","SANTOSBUSD","APEAUD","BIFIUSDT","GMTEUR","IMXBNB","RUNEETH","AVAXGBP","MULTIBTC","MULTIBUSD","MULTIUSDT","APEETH","BSWETH","FILTRY","FTMEUR","GMTGBP","ZILTRY","GMTTRY","WAVESTRY","BTCUST","ASTRBTC","ASTRETH","BSWTRY","FTTETH","FUNBNB","PORTOBUSD","STEEMUSDT","ZILEUR","APEBRL","AUDIOTRY","BTTCBUSD","GMTAUD","MBLBUSD","MOBUSDT","MOBBUSD","MOBBTC","NEXOUSDT","NEXOBUSD","NEXOBTC","REIUSDT","REIBNB","REIETH","GALUSDT","GALBUSD","GALBNB","GALBTC","JASMYEUR","KNCBNB","SHIBGBP","GALEUR","GALTRY","LDOBUSD","LDOUSDT","LDOBTC","ENSTRY","DAREUR","DARETH","ALGOETH","ALGOTRY","GALETH","EPXUSDT","EPXBUSD","RUNETRY","GALBRL","STEEMBUSD","CVCBUSD","REIBUSD","DREPBUSD","AKROBUSD","PUNDIXBUSD","LUNCBUSD","USTCBUSD","OPBTC","OPBUSD","OPUSDT","OGBUSD","KEYBUSD","ASRBUSD","FIROBUSD","NKNBUSD","OPBNB","OPEUR","GTOBUSD","SNXETH","WBTCBUSD","BELETH","LITETH","LEVERUSDT","LEVERBUSD","BURGERETH","PEOPLEETH","UNFIETH","BONDETH","STORJTRY","OPETH","ETCTRY","WINGETH","FILETH","GLMBUSD","SSVBUSD","STGBTC","STGBUSD","STGUSDT","ANKRTRY","ARKBUSD","BETHBUSD","LOOMBUSD","SNMBUSD","AMBBUSD","LUNCUSDT","PHBBUSD","GASBUSD","NEBLBUSD","PROSBUSD","VIBBUSD","GMXBTC","GMXBUSD","GMXUSDT","AGIXBUSD","NEBLUSDT","SNTBUSD","POLYXBTC","POLYXBUSD","POLYXUSDT","APTBTC","APTUSDT","APTBUSD","BTCPLN","ETHPLN","BUSDPLN","APTEUR","APTTRY","APTBRL","QKCBUSD","OSMOBTC","OSMOUSDT","OSMOBUSD","HFTBTC","HFTBUSD","HFTUSDT","ARPAETH","PHBUSDT","VITEBUSD","HOOKBTC","HOOKUSDT","HOOKBUSD","HOOKBNB","MAGICBTC","MAGICBUSD","MAGICUSDT","BUSDRON","HIFIETH","HIFIUSDT","RPLBTC","RPLBUSD","RPLUSDT","PROSUSDT","FETTRY","GFTBUSD","AGIXUSDT","APTETH","BTCRON","GNSUSDT","GNSBTC","SYNBTC","SYNUSDT","VIBUSDT","SSVUSDT","LQTYUSDT","LQTYBTC","AMBUSDT","BETHUSDT","CFXTRY","STXTRY","USTCUSDT","GASUSDT","GLMUSDT","PROMUSDT","QKCUSDT","UFTUSDT","IDBTC","IDBNB","IDUSDT","ARBBTC","ARBUSDT","AGIXTRY","LOOMUSDT","OAXUSDT","ARBTUSD","ARBTRY","ARBEUR","IDTUSD","IDTRY","IDEUR","LDOTUSD","MATICTUSD","OPTUSD","SOLTUSD","SSVTUSD","RDNTBTC","RDNTUSDT","RDNTTUSD"]
   ```