# How can I get all coins in USD parity to the Binance API?

Tags: api, binance, binance-smart-chain, binance-api-client

I need binance data to build a mobile app. Only USDT pairs are sufficient. In the link below it takes all trading pairs, but I only want USDT pairs. Which link should I use for this?

https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price

Comment: Look at this another post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55549499/how-to-retrieve-a-list-of-all-market-pairs-like-eth-btc-using-binance-api

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Binance Exchange API**. There is no need for registering.

The used API call is this: https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo

I recomend you use google colab and python, or any other python resource:

```
import requests

def get_response(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()  # raises exception when not a 2xx response
    if response.status_code != 204:
        return response.json()

def get_exchange_info():
    base_url = 'https://api.binance.com'
    endpoint = '/api/v3/exchangeInfo'
    return get_response(base_url + endpoint)

def create_symbols_list(filter='USDT'):
    rows = []
    info = get_exchange_info()
    pairs_data = info['symbols']
    full_data_dic = {s['symbol']: s for s in pairs_data if filter in s['symbol']}
    return full_data_dic.keys()

create_symbols_list('USDT')
```

**Result**:

```
['BTCUSDT', 'ETHUSDT', 'BNBUSDT', 'BCCUSDT', 'NEOUSDT', 'LTCUSDT',...
```

The api call brings you a very large response fill with with interesting data about the exchange. In the function **create_symbols_list** you get all this data in the **full_data_dic** dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

There is a python [binance client library](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/) and you can do check the list of tickers which tickers are quoted in USDT (and status is trading):

```
from binance.client import Client
client = Client()
info = client.get_exchange_info()
for c in info['symbols']:
    if c['quoteAsset']=='USDT' and c['status']=="TRADING":
        print(c['symbol'])
```